# Unable to find button

Tags: android, kotlin, button

Point of crash:

```
        camera_capture_button.setOnClickListener {
            println("YOYO")
//        takePhoto()

        }
```

The error I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void 
android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

I've added my plugins.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

I've imported:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_experience.*
```

My xml:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/camera_capture_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:text="Take Photo"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:elevation="2dp" />
```

To my understanding I don't need `val CaptureButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.camera_capture_button)`
And when I try, it complains about findViewById

Strangely enough, if I ctrl+click in android studio, my `camera_capture_button` is perfectly connected to the xml.

Here is my entire view:

```
package org.faith.bebetter.ExperiencePage

import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.camera.core.*
import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.faith.bebetter.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_experience.*
import java.io.File
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
typealias LumaListener = (luma: Double) -> Unit

class ExperienceFragment : Fragment() {

    private var preview: Preview? = null
    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null
    private var imageAnalyzer: ImageAnalysis? = null
    private var camera: Camera? = null

    private lateinit var outputDirectory: File
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

//        val CaptureButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.camera_capture_button)
//        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.camera_capture_button)

        // Request camera permissions
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            activity?.let {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        it, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS)
            }
        }

//        outputDirectory = getOutputDirectory()
        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_experience, container, false)

        val CaptureButton = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.camera_capture_button)
        // Setup the listener for take photo button
        CaptureButton.setOnClickListener {
            print("YOYO")
//            takePhoto()
        }

        return view
    }


    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
            requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults:
            IntArray) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
                startCamera()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context,
                        "Permissions not granted by the user.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                activity?.finish()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = context?.let { ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(it) }

        cameraProviderFuture?.addListener(Runnable {
            // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

            // Preview
            preview = Preview.Builder()
                    .build()

            imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
                    .build()

            // Select back camera
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK).build()

            try {
                // Unbind use cases before rebinding
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()

                // Bind use cases to camera
                camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                        this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture)
                preview?.setSurfaceProvider(viewFinder.createSurfaceProvider(camera?.cameraInfo))
            } catch(exc: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
            }

        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context))
    }

    private fun takePhoto() {
        // Get a stable reference of the modifiable image capture use case
        val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return

        // Create timestamped output file to hold the image
        val photoFile = File(
                outputDirectory,
                SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH
                ).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg")

        // Create output options object which contains file + metadata
        val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

        // Setup image capture listener which is triggered after photo has
        // been taken
        imageCapture.takePicture(
                outputOptions, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context), object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
            override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
            }

            override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                val savedUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)
                val msg = "Photo capture succeeded: $savedUri"
                Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.d(TAG, msg)
            }
        })
    }

    private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        context?.let { it1 ->
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    it1, it)
        } == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

//    fun getOutputDirectory(): File {
//        val mediaDir = externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let {
//            File(it, resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() } }
//        return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists())
//            mediaDir else filesDir
//    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "CameraXBasic"
        private const val FILENAME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS"
        private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10
        private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    }

}
```

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/viewFinder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/camera_capture_button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:text="Take Photo"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:elevation="2dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Best regards.

Comment: You're using a `Fragment`, hence you need the rootView as well to access the `Button`. See the variable name where you're inflating the `Gragment` by using `val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourFragmentLayout);` and use this variable as `view.camera_capture_button.setOnClickLisenter{}`. Remember, it doesn't show any compile time error because this is a run-time error. You can also do `val button = view.findViewById(R.id.camera_capture_button)`.

Answer (score 0):

The button has to be called from the context of the view (xml layout).

For example, if that part `camera_capture_button.setOnClickListener { }` is inside `onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)` you need to refer to it as `view.camera_capture_button`. Same goes for `val CaptureButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.camera_capture_button)`, you need to type `val CaptureButton = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.camera_capture_button)`

An other case is that your xml might haven't been inflated yet. It's hard to be more specific if you don't provide any context for each code block.

Comment: I've added my entire Fragment(), could you show me? 

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

When you get that error it means you're trying to make a call to a view that does not belong to the actual context of your code.

It can happen when you're on a fragment's activity onViewCreated method trying to call a button that's inside the Activity's XML. In the fragment's onViewCreated you're allowed to manage it's own views, and no one else's.

In this case though, I think your problem can be that you're placing the listener in a wrong part of the class. Could you provide the whole code of your class, please?

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't need to do the findById() when you use the kotlin extension :) When you ctrl+click the id of the button in your code and it takes you to the correct xml view (I mean your button) it means that you've imported the right button. That's all. It's ID can still be used in a wrong way.

Comment: I've added my entire Fragment(), could you show me? 

Thank you so much.

Comment: Sure :) You have KTX imported, so no need to do the "findViewById" thing. Just use the views ID you've given it in the XML. Also, could you plug in the XML for fragment_experience? Because the problem might be there.

Comment: Done.

The xml file is called: fragment_experience.xml

So how do I do it without the findViewById? What to write

Comment: Try overriding the onViewCreated(). NOT onCreateView(). And then type...
camera_capture_button.setOnClickListener {
            println("YOYO")
        }

Comment: I think I figured it out now. Or it is working. I dunno if my view needed more boundaries in the xml or what happened.

Comment: If I recall correctly, while OnCreateView is running your fragment is still on creation. You could say it's building. Check out the last line of your OnCreateView. It literally returns your fragment's xml inflated. If you're returning the inflated xml in the last line of the method, the views are not created or at least they are not ready to be used until then. The method OnViewCreated is called AFTER the layout is inflated, and every view is now ready for use. In your original code you are trying to set a listener a view that's not ready: on the OnCreateView method.